# Socket io connected and disconected immediately

Tags: ios, node.js, sockets, captivenetwork

I am using SocketIO in my iOS app to connect to Node.js server. Actually if I run my app while I'm connected directly to ISP, I don't have any problem. But if I connect to some public internet which required to use Captive portal technique, my app can never connect to Socket server. Is it because of Captive portal ? How can we bypass this walled garden. We actually can browse internet if we use Safari after inputting SSID and password. But my app think we don't have internet connection.

Could anyone point me out what I did wrong here ? Any help would be much appreciated.

Update : my app can also connect to google.com, I connect to socket server using ip address is that the problem ?

Comment: Your socket.io server in listening on default port 80? If not, that may be you problem, most of the public hotsports are restricting other ports. Some code sample i think would help also.

Comment: Actually socket.io server is listening port 80 by default. The problem maybe because we are behind a walled garden.